# Sending events over RCTEventEmitter from native side to React Native while app is in background

Tags: ios, react-native, ibeacon, react-native-ios

On iOS, when detecting an iBeacon in background mode, I need to send the beacon data to the React-native side in order to perform some API requests.

Currently the app awakes successfully when entering the beacon range, but the event transmitted over the bridge using the `sendEventWithName:body:` method of `RCTEventEmitter` is not received by React-Native.

Is there a way to activate `RCTEventEmitter` on the React-Native side while being in the background? (without rendering any components)

Comment: hi, any idea about this? Same situation here